# How to make a responsive amp-carousel

Tags: amp-html

Is there any way to make a responsive `amp-carousel`?
I've tried to use the attribute `layout="responsive"` on images within the carousel, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-carousel/amp-carousel.md amp-carousel does not currently support layout="responsive"

That means that you can't currently create a responsive amp-carousel.

Please file a new issue: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new to track this feature request.

Comment: Thanks ade! I'll do that.

Comment: In the meantime [this issue has been addressed](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/1531#issuecomment-225461224).

Answer (score 1):

I [filed a new issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/1267#issuecomment-225460668) and layout="responsive" is supported if:

1. the `amp-carousel` is type="slides".
2. the user [adds a CSS rule targeting `amp-img img`](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/1531#issuecomment-174076218) to set `object-fit: contain`.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Bruno's answer this will work if you use layout="responsive" and type="slides" *and* you enable the amp dev channel - https://cdn.ampproject.org/experiments.html

Obviously this is not yet in production.

Answer (score 0):

Mate, use amp-base-carousel instead:

```
<amp-base-carousel loop="true"  width="600" height="400" layout="responsive">
        <amp-img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Ji_G7Bu1MoM/600x400" width="600" height="400" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
        <amp-img src="https://source.unsplash.com/4yCXNMLP9g8/600x400" width="600" height="400" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
        <amp-img src="https://source.unsplash.com/QrgRXH81DXk/600x400" width="600" height="400" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
        <amp-img src="https://source.unsplash.com/8QJSi37vhms/600x400" width="600" height="400" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
    </amp-base-carousel>
```